# Does malloc return an "invalid pointer value" in C++17?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, c++17, object-lifetime

According to C++17 [basic.compound]/3:

> Every value of pointer type is one of the following:
>
> - a pointer to an object or function (the pointer is said to point to the object or function), or
> - a pointer past the end of an object (8.7), or
> - the null pointer value (7.11) for that type, or
> - an invalid pointer value.

The `malloc` function returns a pointer value. Let us assume the call succeeded, so that the return value is not null. The specification of `malloc` ([c.malloc]) does not state that it creates any objects in the returned storage, so it seems like "invalid pointer value" is the least nonsensical category.

Comment: Short answer: [yes.](https://youtu.be/_qzMpk-22cc?t=1400)

Comment: Sidenote: The answer would change in future if [p0593rX](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0593r3.html) standard proposal is adopted.

Comment: I believe this is type dependent.  If you have `int * foo = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));` then you have a value pointer since an `int`'s lifetime starts when storage is acquired.  For something like `std::string` you need to call the constructor so until you do it's invalid.

Comment: None of them make sense currently.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Oh. Hmm.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Are you sure? I think it has to be initialised, even if that's merely default-initialisation ([ref](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1)) - can we say that's happening here?

Comment: Is it an issue, though? Unless you are willing to type-pun, you will have to use placement `new` anyway to get a "meaningful" object, and that doesn't require a valid pointer (only `delete` _does_ require a safely-derived pointer). So I'd say it's all good either way.

Comment: @lightness default initialization is no initialization for `int` so I believe it still applies.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Hmm not quite convinced. Though default-initialisation means nothing, does nothing mean default-initialisation? 

Comment: Yet another proof that the text that tries to specify core C++ is not to be taken literally or seriously.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica That code doesn't acquire storage for an `int` object (it acquires storage with no objects) , objects are only created as specified by [intro.object]/1

Comment: @m.m of course.  That's what I was missing

Answer (score 8):

That makes sense. 
It's an 'invalid pointer value' because it does not point to an object.

See later in that section, where it says:

> A pointer value becomes invalid when the storage it denotes reaches the end of its storage duration

That implies that it's not the "value" of the pointer that makes it invalid, but rather that it does not point to a valid object.

Comment: The text you quote talks about storage, not objects.  And it seems at odds with the quotes in the question.  What about a pointer that points to an object, and then the object is destroyed but the storage is not released?

Comment: Then the pointer becomes an "invalid pointer value"

Answer (score 6):

That is correct.

There is no object at that location in memory. The memory "belongs to you". However, whether a pointer is valid is determined not by memory allocations, but by the existence of an object that it points to. This pointer does not point to any object, so it is an invalid pointer.

[p0593rX](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0593r3.html), if adopted in the future, would change this, basically by putting an object there for you. That's actually quite important, because at the moment any use of `malloc` in C++ I can think of (including placement new) currently has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Actually.... _is_ said placement new valid? Does placement new require a valid pointer input? (Usually it'd be a valid pointer pointing to some `char[]` object) HMM

Comment: It seems that if the pointer value is invalid, then placement new is not guaranteed to work, because in order to call placement new, you need to copy the pointer value into the argument of `::operator new`, which has an implementation-defined result.

Comment: @Brian Yep! Hah. So p0593rX isn't just for fun - malloc is _technically_ useless in C++... (which the proposal does almost say tbf)